# Компиляция с MinGW под Windows. Проблемы с запуском

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, makefile

Мы знаем, что с потоками у MinGW не все гладко, в связи с этим, часто добавляют  -вместо -lpthread флажок -DWINVER=0x0500. Почему полученный экзешник может не запуститься?

И еще: если добавить оба флага -lpthread -DWINVER=0x0500, то компилятор не найдет -lpthread. Почему?

Ситуация такая. По учебе получил задание: сделать в двух CI кроссплатформенное тестирование проекта дипломного. Дипломный проект пишется на С++ и компилируется MinGW. Я не очень шарю в тестах, ну и выбрал google tests. Для того, чтобы посмотреть результаты этого самого теста, нужно скомпилировать сам тест в объект-файл, и еще всякое разное из их исходников. Тк вот их исходники компилируются только с флагом -lpthread. Но так как один сервис CI (AppVeyor) на виндовс, я сразу подумал, что у них этой библиотеки нет - я ее предустановил, но полученный exe не запускается.

```
summator_unittest.exe
Makefile:46: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Error -1073741511
Command exited with code 2
```

Вот мой Мэйкфайл:

```
    ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    $(info Building on Windows/MinGW)
    GET_THE_BALL_ROLLIN = summator_unittest.exe
    CC = g++
    FIN_C = g++ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -DWINVER=0x0500 -lpthread  -o $@
  else
      UNAME_S := $(shell uname -s)
      ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
        $(info Building from Linux)
          GET_THE_BALL_ROLLIN = ./summator_unittest
      CC=i586-mingw32msvc-g++
      FIN_C = g++ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -DWINVER=0x0500 -lpthread -o $@
      endif
  endif


USER_DIR = ../
GTEST_DIR = external/googletest/googletest


CPPFLAGS += -I$(GTEST_DIR)/include
CPPFLAGS += -I$(USER_DIR)

CXXFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra -pthread

TESTS = summator_unittest

GTEST_HEADERS := $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/*.h \
    $(GTEST_DIR)/include/gtest/internal/*.h


CC_AND_OTHER := $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)

FOR_TEST := $(wildcard $(CC_AND_OTHER))
SOURCE_FILES := $(wildcard $(GTEST_HEADERS))

###################################################################

all : $(TESTS) run hello

run:
    $(GET_THE_BALL_ROLLIN)


hello:
    g++ src/hello.cpp -o hello.exe

clean :
    rm -f $(TESTS) obj/gtest.a obj/gtest_main.a *.o obj/*.o

###################################################################
GTEST_SRCS_ = $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.cc $(GTEST_DIR)/src/*.h $(GTEST_HEADERS)

###################################################################
test/gtest-all.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
    $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest-all.cc -DWINVER=0x0500 -lpthread   -o $@

test/gtest_main.o : $(GTEST_SRCS_)
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(GTEST_DIR) $(CXXFLAGS) -c \
        $(GTEST_DIR)/src/gtest_main.cc -DWINVER=0x0500 -lpthread -o $@

test/gtest.a : gtest-all.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

test/gtest_main.a : test/gtest-all.o test/gtest_main.o
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $^

###################################################################
test/summator.o : src/summator.cpp src/summator.h
    g++  -c src/summator.cpp -o $@

test/summator_unittest.o : test/summator_unittest.cpp \
    src/summator.h $(SOURCE_FILES)
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c test/summator_unittest.cpp -o $@

summator_unittest : \
    test/summator.o \
    test/summator_unittest.o \
    test/gtest_main.a
    $(FIN_C)
```

Спасибо.

Comment: А чем оно аргументирует невозможность запуска?